# Find quadratic line of best fit to set of data using partial differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Following question has me stumped.

Find the parabola of the form $y=ax^2+b$ which best fits the points $(1,0),(2,2),(4,4)$ by minimising the sum of the squares, S, given by
$$S=(a+b)^2+(4a+b-2)^2+(16a+b-4)^2$$

I know it involves some sort of expansion and then use partial derivatives to solve the resulting system of linear equations but I'm just not grasping it. Any hints on how to start it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function $S$ depends on parameters $a$ and $b$. To minimize it, you need to love the following system of equations:
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial a}=0\\\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}=0$$
From these, you can find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: thanks. I expanded all the terms and got the partial derivatives with respect to $a$ and $b$ which left me with a system of equations $546a+42b=144$ and $42a+6b=12$.However solving these systems doesnt seem to be giving me the right answer. I will go over my algebra again and see if I made some errors. Thanks again for setting me in the right direction at least.

Comment: I did not check if it's right, but now the last step is to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Also when I expanded the terms I literally only expanded terms in $S$. I have a feeling I need to take into consideration the three points given in some way but I'm not sure how

Comment: I found $a=\frac{5}{21}$ and $b=\frac{1}{5}$ but this isn't the correct answer. Ill check over my work again to make sure.

Comment: What you want is to minimize $\sum_i (y_i-y_i^{fit})^2$. If you plug in $y_i^{fit}=ax_i+b$ into the above equation, you get $S$

Comment: And if you plug in your $a$ and $b$ into the equations that you've just derived, you see that you have made a mistake in your calculations. For example, I get $42a+6b=11.2\ne 12$

Comment: Try with $b=1/3$

Comment: Excellent timing, I just realised my error as you posted that. Basic arithmetic lets me down again. Thanks a million for your help! the answer is correct now